# Unit testing of Wire with ArduinoFake in PlatformIO

Tags: unit-testing, arduino

I'm creating unit tests in PlatformIO using Unity with the ArduinoFake library
I'm trying to test a piece of code that uses the Wire library

When I try to run the unit test (env:native), it complains that the build cannot find <Wire.h>

my platformio.ini file has the following...

```
[env:native]
lib_deps = fabiobatsilva/ArduinoFake@^0.3.1
```

If I comment out *#include <Wire.h>* in the code under test, then the unit test works, so I assume the <Arduino.h> supplied by the ArduinoFake library also provides the necessary references for Wire - but then the build for the Uno platform fails because there's no reference to Wire.h

Anyone used ArduinoFake to test code using Wire? - how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found a solution - wrapped the include in an #ifndef
Not pretty, but does the job

```
#ifndef PIO_UNIT_TESTING
    #include <Wire.h>
#endif
```